# Cascade delete on a foreign key in Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am unable to get the cascade delete to work properly. This is my foreign key table:

```
public class CoverageLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MedicalPlan MedicalPlan { get; set; }  //foreign key
    public virtual VisionPlan VisionPlan { get; set; }    //foreign key
    public virtual DentalPlan DentalPlan { get; set; }    //foreign key
}
```

There are three different ways I tried. When I don't use any fluent API, it sets up the tables and foreign keys appropriately, but cascade delete doesn't work. When I use this code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalPlan>().HasMany(t => t.CoverageLevels).WithOptional.WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

it creates a second column, so I have a completely null `MedicalPlan_Id` and then a `MedicalPlan_Id1` that it fills. When I use this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalPlan>().HasMany(t => t.CoverageLevels).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(d => d.MedicalPlan).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

I get an error creating the database. How can I set up cascade delete properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalPlan>()
    .HasMany(m => m.CoverageLevels)
    .WithOptional(c => c.MedicalPlan)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

...should be the correct mapping. If you omit the lambda expression in `Withoptional(...)` EF assumes that `MedicalPlan.CoverageLevels` has no inverse navigation property in the `CoverageLevel` entity and that `CoverageLevel.MedicalPlan` belongs to another relationship which is the reason for the second foreign key.